# How to make an Ember component with svg.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, svg.js

I am working with ember, and I have seen components written like this:

```js
App.ExampleComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    render: function (buffer) {
        //Push strings to the buffer
    }
});
```

However, I am hoping to create an ember component that draws on a canvas using [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/), which can only use the DOM. So, what I would like to do is

```js
App.ExampleComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    render: function (element) {
        var canvas = SVG(element);
    }
});
```

Is there any way to do this with Ember?

Note: I need [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/) to retain its references to the SVG elements, so that I can color them without redrawing the entire image [which takes a long time to render]. I think this prohibits me from simply stringifying the element into buffer, but perhaps not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to manipulate a DOM tree only by svg.js you must avoid calling Em.Component.render() on property changes and call only svg.js related functions.

I guess you need to start with something like this: http://jsbin.com/AfEQoQo/4/edit

**Short explanation:**
First, in your custom Em.Component implementation, you need to prepare simple template and initialize svg.js in didInsertElement Ember.Component callback somehow like this:

```
// Create simple wrapper template for svg.js content
template: Em.Handlebars.compile('<div id="svg-wrapper"></div>'),

didInsertElement: function() {
  // Create and save the svg.js context for
  // later manipulations
  var draw = SVG('svg-wrapper');
  this.set('draw', draw);
}
```

After that you have you svg.js context ready and can process further with rendering. So let's implement some drawing:

```
svgRender: function() {
  // Manipulate your SVG dom tree here
  var draw = this.get('draw');
  draw.rect(50,50).fill('#f09');    
}
```

Now, you can call this function either from init implemented above or trigger it via some observers like I do in the [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/AfEQoQo/4/edit). Hope this helps.